# Is there a way to center the content on a sub-pixel level?

Tags: css, sass

The simplest question is, how do I vertically center the content here. Is there a way for me to sacrifice legibility in order to get geometrical precision?

[image]

I tried `text-rendering: geometricPrecision` no luck.

```html
<div 
  style="
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    left: 30px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: green;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 10px;
    text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
  ">
  2
</div>
```

---

Here are some micro-adjustments so you can see how I want it to look like:

```html
<div 
  style="
        position: relative;
        top: 30px;
        left: 30px;
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
        background: green;
        border-radius: 50%;
        font-size: 0;
        text-align: center;
  ">
    <div 
      style="
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-family: monospace;
            line-height: 10px;
            font-size: 8px;
            transform: translate3d(5%, 7%, 0);
            color: white;
      ">
      2
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if all you're interested in doing is getting content to center vertically I would take a look at flex box, but I'm not sure what you mean by sub-pixel levels

Comment: @Pete @Culyx subpixel transformations are achieved with `transform`. Updated the question with details.

Comment: @Pete Please do some research into [subpixel rendering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering). It is not monitor dependent and is a technique browsers have been using for years.

Comment: A specific character doesn't necessarily render in the vertical center of the line-height of any given font, so you might be perfectly centering the text and it still looks off.  If so, you'll have to manually tweak.